# Ladder function in BigQuery SQL

Tags: google-bigquery

In the example below, I would like to have kind of a sliding ladder function, with number 4 as a trigger threshold for incrementation

```sql
SELECT 
  t, 
  -- f(t) as u
FROM UNNEST([1, 2, 4, 1, 2, 3, 5, 1, 2, 3, 3]) as t


-- expected result
+---+---+
| t | u |
+---+---+
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 | -- increment u since 4 >= 4 has been found
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 5 | 3 | -- increment u since 5 >= 4 has been found
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 3 | 3 |
+---+---+
```

How can I implement f(t) to achieve that, maybe WINDOW functions ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [UNNEST WITH OFFSET](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays#flattening_arrays) and COUNTIF() OVER():

```
SELECT 
  t, 
  1 + COUNTIF(t >= 4) OVER (ORDER BY offset) as u
FROM UNNEST([1, 2, 4, 1, 2, 3, 5, 1, 2, 3, 3]) as t WITH OFFSET as offset
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot again ! How about if I only deal with a column not an ARRAY ?

`WITH A as (
SELECT t
FROM UNNEST([1, 2, 4, 1, 2, 3, 5, 1, 2, 3, 3]) t
)

SELECT ... FROM A`

Comment: Found it, `ROW_NUMBER() OVER() as offset` works the same way !